# How to setup ECS with two active container ports

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have a docker image with 2 ports exposed, `5000` for backend and `4200` for front-end and I use PM2 to start the 2 services (docker works locally fine), am trying to build cdk for that, in the ECS service log, I can see that PM2 has started the 2 services and they should be running as expected, bu,in the `deployment` tab, the stack gets stuck with error

`service express-app-service instance i-09364a536df663f23 port 4200 is unhealthy in target-group Expres-ECSAL-HAHCQJM1YTBJ  due to (reason Health checks failed)`

1. I'd like to know how can I set health check properly (should be for
   the 2 ports ?)  given that I have 2 ports (I already have health
   check point in the backend).
2. how can I make 443 requests directs to port 4200(front-end) ?

these are code snippets of what I have now

```
const container = taskDefinition.addContainer("AppContainer", ..)
container.addPortMappings(
      {
        containerPort: 5000,
        hostPort: 5000,
        protocol: ecs.Protocol.TCP
      },
      {
        containerPort: 4200,
        hostPort: 4200,
        protocol: ecs.Protocol.TCP
      }
    )



const listener = ecsALB.addListener('HttpListener', {
      certificates: [sslCertificate],
      protocol: elbv2.ApplicationProtocol.HTTPS,
      sslPolicy: elbv2.SslPolicy.FORWARD_SECRECY_TLS12_RES,
      port: 443,
    });


    /**
     * Set that requests coming into our listener should be
     * redirected to our service containers (express servers).
     */
    listener.addTargets('ECS_ALB_ServerTarget', {
      port: 443,
      healthCheck: {
        path: "/signin",
        enabled: true,
        protocol: ecs.Protocol.HTTP
      },
      protocol: elbv2.ApplicationProtocol.HTTP,
      targets: [service.loadBalancerTarget({
        containerName: 'express-app-container',
        containerPort: 4200,
      })],
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers to your questions:

1. Usually the port mapping of your container is used when performing the health check. So the endpoint for doing the health check in your case will be something like

   `http://<ecs-container-ip>:4200/signin`

   if this is successful and
   returns a http code `200`, the health check passes.
2. Yes, it is possible and is usually the case. The HTTPS (443) connection is terminated on the load balancer and a new connection is initiated towards your ECS container.

I think you should update the target port to the following, which is pointing to your frontend.

```
listener.addTargets('ECS_ALB_ServerTarget', {
      port: 4200,
      ...
```

Port is defined as such:

> [The port on which the target receives traffic.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2.ApplicationTargetGroup.html#port)

It is also worth checking if the security group of the container is allowing for incoming traffic on port `4200` from the load balancer.

```
targets: [service.loadBalancerTarget({
```

[The code above is registering the container with the target group which was created.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2.ApplicationTargetGroup.html#targets)

Comment: how do I get the container `<ecs-container-ip>` ?

Comment: You do not need to manage that, I was just explaining how AWS create the URL to perform the health check on your container.

Comment: what if I need health-check to be performed on port 5000 and normal requests be on 4200 ? how do I do that ?

Comment: You first need to have a valid endpoint which is exposed on the port 5000 and then add the port 5000 in the health check object; https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2.HealthCheck.html#port

The rest stays the same.

Comment: omg, this was what am looking for ! :D

Comment: what is the difference between the port I set in `addTargets` and the one in that can also be set in `loadBalancerTarget` ?

Comment: The `addTargets` is adding a *target group* to the listener. A target group is defining which port and protocol are used to send traffic to the targets associated with that target group. The `loadBalancerTarget` is simply  registering the application with the target group and also mentioning the port on which the application will be receiving traffic on. The port of the application and the port of the target group should be in sync.

Comment: It looks a bit reduntant to redefine application port when registering it with the target group but it is how AWS works..

Comment: becuase I saw this ... https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/blob/master/typescript/ecs/ecs-service-with-advanced-alb-config/index.ts and it seems they use different ports which got me abit confused

Comment: This is perfectly normal as well, since the application will also register itself automatically with the target group if it is not registered. Doing this `service.loadBalancerTarget({` is simply registering the application manually when we are configuring the target group.

Comment: am still abit confused honestly, why is he using 2 different ports ? ( you mentioned before they should be in sync) that made sense, but I can't understand how the 2 ports are different

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed out on that part. From my experience, the ports must be in sync. I think he is forcing the container to register with that target group. This is what the documentation says as well, `May be required, Forces new resource`; https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lb_target_group.html#port